# GTM2 Trigger on <i class="icon-time">

Tags: google-tag-manager

I need to insert a html tag on any page that has an i tag and class=icon-time code looks like;

```
<i class="icon-large icon-time">
```

I have tried all variations of DOM Elements with CSS-Selector but cant get this to work, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested this and it seems to work fine with a DOM element. On top of my head I see two possible issues:

- you might have forgotten to include the dot in the CSS selector (it's `.icon-time`, not '`icon-time`' or something).
- you may have tried to trigger the tag on a standard pageview. That doesn't work since DOM elements can only be accessed after the DOM has rendered (standard pageviews trigger as soon as the GTM code has loaded). Try to create a new pageview trigger with "Dom ready" as trigger type.

If that doesn't help you need to provide more information.

This is  what I did:

[image]

After that the Variable "Icon Large" contained the value of the class attribute (i.e. "icon-large icon-time") and I was able to use that in a rule ("Icon large contains icon-time").

Comment: OK, thanks wasnt waiting for DOM Ready, but its still not working.

Comment: OK, thanks for  your help, I wasnt waiting for DOM Ready, but its still not working.

When creating the variable type=DOM Element, Selection Method = CSS Selector and Element Selector = i ?

Then Trigger= Page View, Type DOM Ready and fires on = my-variable  Matches CSS Selector  = .icon-time ?

Comment: I used the element selector .icon-time for testing. GTM apparently only evaluates the first occurence of the selector, so if theres an i-tag before your desired tag the latter will be ignored. I'll send you a few screenshots later to show what worked for me (right now I'm at the office so this will take a while).